# How to apply a custom option to all products in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm having problem with my new magento site, I want to apply a custom option to all the products on my site. Basically I want to add the custom pricing option for large sizes (my site is about motorcycle leather jackets etc), so if someone chooses a size that requires extra amount, there should be an option for that. I can apply this option to one product at a time. Does somebody know how to apply this to all products at one? Here's the link for my site: http://www.lopeholt.com
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple hack to do this.

However, there is a free extension to copy custom options to multiple products which could help you to save lots of work:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-copy-delete-custom-options-on-multiple-products.html

Update: extension isn't free anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerard! You did save me a lot of work and time. I didn't know any free extension really existed. Before this, I did a lot of research to find a free extension but couldn't.

Comment: thanks for you hint! It's a pity that the extension isn't free anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add custom options to multiple products,same functionality is provided by following extension which could help to save your time to assign custom options to multiple products.
You can also set custom option for different sizes(large sizes).

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-manger.html

Comment: Hello Empiro Technologies!
Your answer really helped a lot!
Its true that the medma extension isn't free anymore, but yours is working fine as I tested it on several sites.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like "Custom Option Manager" isn't free anymore. It happens a lot in the industry. Whenever an extensions gets famous, the developers make it premium.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this completely for free without relying on extensions you can use Magmi. It takes a little while to get used to but it allows you to import almost anything for your product database - **here's the link to the Magmi tutorial:**
https://understandinge.com/course/importing-products-magento/

**Link to the Custom Options upload instructions:**
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Custom_Options#File_to_upload_field